# How do you mock out private properties with OCMock for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, unit-testing, ocmock

I have a private property that is declared in the .m file of my class to be tested, let's call it ClassUnderTest.  ClassUnderTest instantiates an instance of ClassToBeMocked.  How do I use OCMock to mock out an instance of the ClassToBeMocked and assign it to the ClassUnderTest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-do-i-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Re-declare the property in your test class. You can do the same for private methods. In ClassUnderTestTest.m:

```
@interface ClassUnderTest ()

@property(retain)ClassToBeMocked *instanceToBeMocked;

-(void)somePrivateMethod;

@end
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is beautiful.  I totally forgot about that aspect of Objective-C ;-)

Comment: @abellina no you can't currently mock class methods with OCMock

Answer (score 1):

Does the following work?

```
id classUnderTest = ... // get from somewhere
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[ClassToBeMocked class]];
[classUnderTest setValue:mock forKey:@"nameOfThatPrivateProperty"];
```

Not totally sure whether you can set private properties like this. I think it depends on what kind of property it is.

Comment: Can you get properties like this as well?

Comment: Yes - this is just using KVC within the Foundation framework. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1