# why I can access private method in unit test class in my case

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

Say I have a private method `-(void) doSomething` defined in m file of `School` class (it is not declared in interface header):

```
@implementation School
-(void) doSomething {
   ...
}
@end
```

I have a unit test case for `School` class:

```
@interface SchoolTest : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation SchoolTest
 - (void)testExample {
   id mySchoolMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[School new]];
   // I know I can't access '-(void)doSomething' since it is a private method
 }
@end
```

I know I normally can't access this private method. But if I re-declare the `-(void) doSomething` in my test class as below:

```
@interface SchoolTest : XCTestCase
// re-declare it in my test class
-(void) doSomething
@end

@implementation SchoolTest
 - (void)testExample {
   id mySchoolMock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:[School new]];
   // Now I can access '-(void)doSomething'!!! Why now I can access the private method in `mySchool` Instance in my test class ? 
  [mySchoolMock doSomething]; 
 }
@end
```

Why in above way I can access **private method** of `School` class with `mySchool` instance? What is the objective-c theory behind this?

(I am doing this because I have read the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893502/how-do-you-mock-out-private-properties-with-ocmock-for-ios), but I don't understand why we can do it? what is the theory behind?)

Comment: There's really no such thing as a private method in ObjC.  There are only methods the compiler pretends it can't see from certain perspectives.  I am unsure why your code doesn't at least trigger a warning that `doSomething` is an unknown selector.  Is your code not using ARC?

Comment: @Avi, yes, ARC is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C lacks protection mechanism for methods and fields that would be active at run time. All "protection" is done at compile time, when you hide the method in `.m` file to make it "private".

Once the method is compiled, its information is stored in a table that is used to dispatch method invocations at runtime. Anyone who has the selector for your method can invoke it, as if it were public. This enables a lot of dynamic behavior in Objective-C.

Unfortunately, there is no protection of selectors at runtime. When you re-declare the private method for testing, you are essentially telling Objective-C that you know that the method is there, and insist on letting you make a call.

Two things could happen when you do this: if the method is actually there, the call is going to succeed. If the method is not there, however, you would end up with a crash on calling an invalid selector.

> the method is re-delclared in my test class not in School class

This part is slightly tricky. `id` is a special type, which allows you to call any method with very little compile-time checking. Basically, the compiler verifies that there is any type that it knows that has a method with the matching signature, and then it lets you make the call. This is similar to creating a `@SELECTOR` for your method, and then calling it dynamically on an `id`-typed object. Essentially, the compiler verifiers that you didn't make an obvious typo, and lets the call to proceed.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but 1. Could you please be more specific, especially the last paragraph in your answer,  `if the method is actually there, the call is going to succeed. If the method is not there ...`.  So what does `there` mean in my example? 2. What I don't understand is the method is re-delclared in my test class not in School class, but I am able to call this private method on my School instance after re-declared it in test class (very weird to me). Do you mean once a method is declared no matter where, it is visible by any class at runtime?

Comment: @Leem.fin 1. In your case the method is there, because the implementation has code to handle the no-argument call to `doSomething`. If your re-declaration was 'doSomethingElse', the compiler would let you compile, but the call would crash at run-time. 2. I answered this part in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that you didn't "redeclare" the method - you added a `doSomething` method to `SchoolTest` class. This is much different from what was mentioned in the linked answer - there a category was used to show "private" methods to the test class. So something like this would be better :

```
@interface School (Tests)
    - (void)doSomething;
@end
```

What you did worked, because `mySchoolMock` is of `id` type, and `doSomething` was a visible symbol, so Xcode and compilers didn't warn you about anything, and it worked because mechanisms explained by @dasblinkenlight did their job at runtime.